# Swift on Ubuntu: use of undeclared type 'NSFileHandle'

Tags: ubuntu, swift3

am running swift 3.0.2 on Ubuntu.

when I run the following code

```
 import Foundation
 let file: NSFileHandle? = NSFileHandle(forReadingAtPath: "data.txt")
```

I get an error of

test.swift:274:11: error: use of undeclared type 'NSFileHandle'
let file: NSFileHandle? = NSFileHandle(forReadingAtPath: "data.txt")

NSFileHandle is in the APIs for Foundation though is this true for the Foundation library on Linux?

What am I doing wrong?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [SE-0086 Drop NS Prefix in Swift Foundation](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0086-drop-foundation-ns.md):

> As part of Swift 3 API Naming and the introduction of Swift Core Libraries, we are dropping the NS prefix from key Foundation types in Swift.

`NSFileHandle` is in that list and is called `FileHandle` in Swift 3:

```
import Foundation
let file = FileHandle(forReadingAtPath: "data.txt")
```

This applies to the Apple platforms and to Linux. 
The Linux implementation can be seen here: 
[NSFileHandle.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Foundation/NSFileHandle.swift).

There is a discussion [[swift-evolution] Pitch: Replacement for FileHandle](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20170213/031949.html)
about undoing the renaming and implementing `FileHandle` in a more
Swift-like manner (such as `throw`ing Swift errors instead of 
`NSException`s).